# CSS: Stacked div elements, when hover only the hovered div gets border

Tags: css

I have some stacked *div* elements. On hover each of them gets border.

Now when I hover *div*, the hovered one, and its parent *div* are getting borders.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zekw31gq/1/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="button1">
        <div class="button11">
            <div class="button12"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I cannot manage to create the following:

When a *div* is hovered only the hovered *div* must get border?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: afaik this is not possible. Maybe there is another solution to what you want to achieve? With the has: this would be possible, but this isn't implemented yet https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has like: div:hover:has(div:hover)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute positioning and place your divs inside a relatively positioned element. Here's the updated fiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/zekw31gq/4/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="red"></div>
  <div id="blue"></div>
  <div id="black"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
#red {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:red;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
}
#blue {
  position: absolute;
  margin:25px;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  background:blue;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
}
#black {
  position: absolute;
  margin:50px;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:black;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
}
#red:hover {
  border-color: darkred;
}
#blue:hover {
  border-color: darkblue;
}
#black:hover {
  border-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: No worries. I've updated CSS so that the container size matches the largest element. This will make sure no elements after the continer get hidden by its child elements.